# How to append an int to the end of a string argument for getElementByID()

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to append an integer to the end of an argument of type string for the getElementByID method... in this example latest==2. And i want to search for the id "number2".

```
number=document.getElementById("number"&latest);
```

This current syntax is giving me issues.

Additionally, if i want to dynamically insert HTML, how would one go about inserting that value into the data field for a label

```
cell1 = row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',<span><label for="2" id="label2">2</label></span>
```

All the "2"'s here should be dynamic, like if i were to reference a global counter n...

Comment: Replace `&` with `+`. `+` does addition and string concatenation (you're "adding" things to strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know how to append an integer to the end of an argument of type string for the getElementByID method..........

Simply use **'+'** operator

```
var latest = 2;
var number = document.getElementById( "number" + latest );
```

See string operations : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

> if i want to dynamically insert HTML ........

Suppose **globalNumber** is a global variable and its value is 2

then correct syntax for your second query is

```
cell1 = row.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<span><label for="' +  globalNumber + '" id="label' + globalNumber + '" >' +  globalNumber + '</label></span>' );
```

This

```
'<span><label for="' +  globalNumber + '" id="label' + globalNumber + '" >' +  globalNumber + '</label></span>'
```

will give you

```
<span><label for="2" id="label2" >2</label></span>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Very clear and useful feedback thank you very much @Priyesh Kumar